# identity of integration

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

In 1D, we have the well-known identity 
$$
\varphi(y)-\varphi(x)= \displaystyle\int_x^y \varphi'(t) dt, \ (x,y) \in (a,b).
$$
My question is: there exist the analogue of this identity in 2D (function with two variables)? We can write $\varphi(y_1,y_2)-\varphi(x_1,x_2)$ as an integrale? Please.

Comment: When you say 2D, do you mean a function $f:\mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R^2$ or $f:\mathbb R^2\longrightarrow \mathbb R$?

Comment: Stoke's theorem (divergence theorem of Gauss, Green's theorem), see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem

Comment: $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0):

Green's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem is what I think is closest to what you asked for.

Comment: I don't understant how this theorem can help me. If $\varphi$ is an function for two variables $x_1$ and $x_2$. We can write $\varphi(y_1,y_2)-\varphi(x_1,x_2)$ as an integrale?

Comment: No, you need two functions and the integral along the boundary will be equal to the integral of a certain differential of those functions over the area.

Comment: Not sure what your question is, either the answer is no with some silly counterexample or there are some hidden assumption in your question or it's trivially reducible to the one-dimensional case by a curve from (x1,x2) to (y1,y2) and the field being conservative.